# Is it possible to integrate existing JSP pages in Joomla 3 CMS?

Tags: java, php, javascript, joomla

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Include a JSP in a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110312/how-to-include-a-jsp-in-a-php-page)

I have pre-developed `JSP` pages with `CSS` and `Javascript` code.
I want to know that : can I use these pages on `Joomla` which is using `WAMP` server?
I did not get any option in `Joomla` to add any page in it.

Comment: yes you can please refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110312/how-to-include-a-jsp-in-a-php-page